# I'm completely knowledgeless of this error. What's causing this and how could I fix it?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I run my code with **node .** and got this error. Is there something I could fix that's causing this problem?

```
    throw new RangeError('BITFIELD_INVALID', bit);
    ^

RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\huawei\Downloads\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:152:11)
    at C:\Users\huawei\Downloads\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:147:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\huawei\Downloads\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:147:40)
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\huawei\Downloads\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:550:33)
    at new Client (C:\Users\huawei\Downloads\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:76:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\huawei\Downloads\DiscordBot\index.js:7:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'BITFIELD_INVALID'
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more code?

Comment: this is an error in the terminal

Comment: can you provide us the code, because it would be easy for the community to find solution afterwards.

Comment: but like, what code? I have many code files

Comment: share the code of file where you are calling this function.

Comment: it shows there is an error in index file, so can you please show us?

Comment: @Anonymous can we see the file at which you specify your intents?

Comment: If my answer worked, make sure to mark it as the best answer! You can also upvote if you are not the owner.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error usually occurs when you have specified no intents. See what intents are [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#gateway-intents). See the full list of intents [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS). Your code when you initialize `Client` should look like this plus the intents you want:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    ]
});
```

**Hoped this helped!**